# How to call a specific method only if class has one?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, c++17

I have a tuple of objects of different classes. I want to iterate over the tuple and call a certain method only if those class has one.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
struct A {  int get( ) { return 5; }; };
struct B { }; 
struct C {  int get( ) { return 10; }; };
int i = 0;
tuple<A, B, C> t;
for ( auto t_element : t ) 
{
    if constexpr ( has_get_method( decltype(t_element) ) )
    {
        i += t_element.get( );
    }
}
```

I already know how to iterate over the tuple and check if a class has some method using sfinae but how do I skip object that do not have the required method?

**EDIT:**
If you found this old question in the future, please know that this can be done much easier now using concepts from C++20 standard.

Comment: `if constexpr` id c++17; you tagged c++14; do you mean c++17?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Comment: You can't iterate over tuples using a ranged-for anyway, so even if you get the SFINAE for member-function existence to work, the iteration still won't work the way you want.

Comment: you could get the indices of the types that supports a call to your "member function", then use a recursive `std::get<I>` on the tuple, for each of those indices.

Comment: `std::apply([&](auto&&... elements) { ([&](auto&& element) { /* if constexpr here */ }(std::forward<decltype(elements)>(elements)), ...) }, t);` to iterate but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a type-traits, to check if a class has a `get()` method, by  declaring a couple of functions (no need to define them)

```
template <typename>
constexpr std::false_type withGetH (long);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto withGetH (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().get(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using withGet = decltype( withGetH<T>(0) );
```

The following is a fully working c++17 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
constexpr std::false_type withGetH (long);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto withGetH (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().get(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using withGet = decltype( withGetH<T>(0) );

struct A {  int get( ) { return 5; }; };
struct B { }; 
struct C {  int get( ) { return 10; }; };

template <typename T>
int addGet (T & t)
 {
   int ret { 0 };

   if constexpr ( withGet<T>{} )
      ret += t.get();

   return ret;
 }

int main ()
 {
   int i = 0;

   std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

   i += addGet(std::get<0>(t));
   i += addGet(std::get<1>(t));
   i += addGet(std::get<2>(t));

   std::cout << i << std::endl;
 }
```

If you can't use `if constexpr`, you can write (in c++11/14) `getAdd()` as follows, using tag dispatching

```
template <typename T>
int addGet (T & t, std::true_type const &)
 { return t.get(); }

template <typename T>
int addGet (T & t, std::false_type const &)
 { return 0; }

template <typename T>
int addGet (T & t)
 { return addGet(t, withGet<T>{}); }
```

**--EDIT--**

The OP ask

> my code needs to check for a templated method with parameters. Is it possible to modify your solution so that instead of int `get()` it could check for something like `template<class T, class U> void process(T& t, U& u)`?

I suppose it's possible.

You can create a type-traits `withProcess2` (where 2 is the number of arguments) that receive three template type parameters: the class and the two template types

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
constexpr std::false_type withProcess2H (long);


template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
constexpr auto withProcess2H (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().process(std::declval<U>(),
                                          std::declval<V>()),
                std::true_type{} );

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
using withProcess2 = decltype( withProcess2H<T, U, V>(0) );
```

The following is a fully working example (c++17, but now you know how to make it c++14) with `A` and `C` with a `process()` with 2 template parameters and `B` with a `process()` with only 1 template parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename, typename>
constexpr std::false_type withProcess2H (long);


template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
constexpr auto withProcess2H (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().process(std::declval<U>(),
                                          std::declval<V>()),
                std::true_type{} );

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
using withProcess2 = decltype( withProcess2H<T, U, V>(0) );

struct A
 {
   template <typename T, typename U>
   void process(T const &, U const &)
    { std::cout << "A::process(T, U)" << std::endl; }
 };

struct B
 {
   template <typename T>
   void process(T const &)
    { std::cout << "B::process(T)" << std::endl; }
 };

struct C
 {
   template <typename T, typename U>
   void process(T &, U &)
    { std::cout << "C::process(T, U)" << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename T>
void callProcess (T & t)
 {
   static int  i0 { 0 };
   static long l0 { 0L };

   if constexpr ( withProcess2<T, int &, long &>{} )
      t.process(i0, l0);
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

   callProcess(std::get<0>(t)); // print A::process(T, U)
   callProcess(std::get<1>(t)); // no print at all
   callProcess(std::get<2>(t)); // print C::process(T, U)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me except my code needs to check for a  templated method with parameters. Is it possible to modify you solution so that instead of `int get()` it could check for something like `template<class T, class U> void process(T& t, U& u)`?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov - yes, I think it's possible; answer improved.

Answer (score 6):

Just write a sfinae'd function and a *catchall* in case the previous one fails. You don't have to use `if constexpr` for that and you can't use it actually in C++14 (that is how you tagged the question).
Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

auto value(...) { return 0; }

template <typename T>
auto value(T &t) -> decltype(t.get()) {
    return t.get();
}

struct A { int get() { return 5; }; };
struct B {}; 
struct C { int get() { return 10; }; };

int main() {
   int i = 0;

   std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

   i += value(std::get<0>(t));
   i += value(std::get<1>(t));
   i += value(std::get<2>(t));

   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ON3X3up4q4oKzM3l).

If you have any argument you want to use to test it, you can use `std::forward` as:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto value(T &t, Args&&... args)
-> decltype(t.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{ return t.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

Then invoke it as:

```
i += value(std::get<0>(t), params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me except my code needs to check for a  templated method with parameters. Is it possible to modify you solution so that instead of `int get()` it could check for something like `template<class T, class U> void process(T& t, U& u)`?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov You know what parameters to pass in?

Comment: @skypjak not sure I understood you correctly, but yes, I know the types of those parameters from the code with tuple.